# How to prevent a method returning a Future from being invoked until a previous call does not complete

Tags: scala, playframework, future

I have a `Play` plugin that executes a method every 15 seconds like this:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import play.api.{Application, Plugin}
import akka.actor.Cancellable

class AuthPlugin(app: Application) extends Plugin {

  private var cancellableTokenDelete: Option[Cancellable] = None

  ...

  override def onStart = {
    cancellableTokenDelete = Some(
      Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(0.seconds, 15.seconds) {
        discardExpiredTokens
      }
    )
  }

  override def onStop = {
    cancellableTokenDelete.foreach(_.cancel)
  }
}

object AuthPlugin {

  ...

  def discardExpiredTokens: Future[Unit] = {
    tokenTraceService.removeExpired.recover {
      case NonFatal(e) => Logger.error("error discarding expired tokens", e)
    }.map { _ => }
  }
}
```

Even if after 15 seconds `discardExpiredTokens` hasn't finished yet, it gets still invoked again by the scheduler... but this is not what I'm looking for.

That said, how do I prevent the scheduler from invoking `discardExpiredTokens` when a previous call is still executing? I need a mechanism that let me by-pass the call to `discardExpiredTokens` until something like a Mutex is not released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a very simple way to achieve this, if you use `scheduleOnce` instead of `schedule`, then the last call in the scheduled action could be to call `scheduleOnce` again.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/scheduler.html